# Battling to display nested data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, model-associations

So I have a form with nested data that is correctly displaying in the form and is being correctly saved. However, I'm now working on trying to display this data and I'm really battling.

So I have a lot of data, but will focus on two specific types of data:

I have users, and users can create projects. The two data fields I'm battling with related to projects are:

- Each project has a budget (stored as a budget_id on the project table, and for which I want to call the name of the budget)
- Each project a bunch of features through a features_projects join table

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :budget
  has_and_belongs_to_many :features
end
```

**Budget Model**

```
class Budget < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**Features Model**

```
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

Extract of the index method from the **Projects Controller**

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all
end
```

**Project View** to show the index

```
    <div class="container dashboard">
      <div class="center">
        <h1> Your Projects</h1>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Budget</th>
            <th>User_id</th>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <% @projects.each do |project| %>
            <tr>
              <% if project.user == current_user %>
                <td><%= project.description %></td>
                <td><%= project.budget_id %></td>
                <td><%= project.user.email if project.user %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Show', project, class: "btn btn-info btn-sm" %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project), class: "btn btn-warning btn-sm" %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
              <% end %>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <br>
      <div class="center">
        <%= link_to 'New Project', new_project_path, class:"btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I basically want to be able to display the budget saved for each project as well as the list of features that they chose. I have been trying a few different things from solutions online, but haven't had any luck :( I think perhaps I need to create a @budget variable perhaps under the index method, but I haven't had any luck with that either. Could anyone kindly help explain how I would do this?

Thanks so much!

**UPDATE**
Using project.budget.name reveals the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Projects#index

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column budgets.project_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "budgets".* FROM "budgets" WHERE "budgets"."project_...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that:

> Each project has a budget (stored as a budget_id on the project table, and for which I want to call the name of the budget)

This is not how `has_one` works, it will expect a `project_id` on the budget table.

I think you need to use `belongs_to`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

Answer (score 0):

```
project.budget.name #give name of budget 
project.features do |feature|
  feature.name # gives feature name
end
```

Comment: Thanks I did try that but got an error - I've update the question to show the error